# How to add different background image or color on every page in NEXT JS

Tags: css, next.js, background

Tech stack: Next JS, Typescript and tailwind.

Problem: I want to use new background image on every page **including the navbar**. I dont know how do i architect my application in such way.
Because if i add ny navbar in layout.tsx then i wont be able to change the background of Navbar.

Solution from chatGPT: Use HOC, great solution. But again, You will have to use on every page.

Please let me know if you have better solution.

I can always go back and violet DRY. But I want clean solution.

Comment: Make your Navbar a client component and use the `usePathname` hook to show a background on each route you may desire.